# How do I run a callback on Model A when object on Model B is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If I have

```
Class A 
 has_many :b

 after_save :run_method

 protected
 def update_expiration
     //
 end

Class B 
 belongs_to :a
```

When an object in B is updated I need to run an update on A to change an expiration date. The problem is the method on A is protected so I can't call it from a callback inside B. I just want :update_expiration to run when a change is made for B.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A 
  has_many :b

  after_save :run_method
  B.after_save :update_expiration

  protected

  def update_expiration
      # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: What is there to explain? I changed one line that is self explanatory.

Comment: This didn't work. Results in undefined local variable or method `update_expiration'